# How to verify if a mysql database is reachable quickly in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql server running on my local network that isn't reachable off the network, and it needs to stay like this.

When I am on a different network the following code hangs for about 5-10 seconds, my guess is that its retrying to connect for a number of attempts:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="Address",
            user="user",
            password="password",
            database="database"
)
```

Is there a way to "ping" the mysql server before this code to verify that the MySQL server is reachable or limit the number of retries?

At the moment I am having to use a try-except clause to catch if the server is not reaachable.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) you can use `connection_timeout` to adjust the timeout. If you set it to a low value (seems like it's in seconds - so `1` should work fine) you'll get the behavior you're looking for (and it will also help you catch any issues with the user/password/database values)

Comment: @MatsLindh Perfect this is what I need. If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to implement specific behavior before connecting, adjust the connect timeout so that you don't have to wait - according to your need, the server is down if you can't connect within a short timeframe anyway.

You [can use `connection_timeout` to adjust the socket timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) used when connecting to the server.

If you set it to a low value (seems like it's in seconds - so `1` should work fine) you'll get the behavior you're looking for (and it will also help you catch any issues with the user/password/database values).